# Hide customer navigation links based on user group

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, ifconfig

I would like to hide link in user account `customer_account.xml` based on role they are in. Let say we have group B2B and i want to hide block `customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link`.

To remove this block I need flowing code:
`<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>`

To remove it in condition i know that I will require ifconfig
`<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" ifconfig="??" remove="true"/>`

However i have no idea how to get that true/false condition here. Is this require special class if so were to put it and how it might look ?

Comment: Is any solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to conditionally remove block from layout use Magento 2 event `layout_generate_blocks_after` as below.

Define the event in `events.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer instance="Vendor\YourModule\Observer\Frontend\Removeblocks" name="layout_generate_blocks_after"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Define Observer file `Removeblocks.php` and add below code in file.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourModule\Observer\Frontend;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class Removeblocks implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //your condition here
       $layout = $observer->getLayout();
       $layout->unsetElement('customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link');
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: execute should be (\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to pull in values like that within the XML as it will be on a per-customer basis and the ifconfig values are static.

Your best bet will probably be to write a plugin for the `_toHtml()` function in

**vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Link/Current.php**

where the individual links are rendered.

You could then use the Magento\Customer\Model\Session class to get the customer group ID (`$customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();`) which you can check before rendering the unwanted item.